# redirect API URL that is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I am looking for guidance.
we have api url that is

```
something.com/foo1/bar

something.com/foo2/bar
```

We are hosting the service using AWS ALB and also nginx on instances.

I am wondering if I can handle gracefully if they are trying anything that is

```
something.com/foo3/bar

something.com/abc/bar ..etc
```

In general,  I am wondering if I can use AWS ALB rule or nginx conf to redirect or return 301 to user?

I am not sure how to work on this one.

Please help.

Comment: What does "handle gracefully" mean, here, exactly?  If the wrong path is requested, you should typically return an error, because an error has been made -- particularly on an API endpoint -- so I'm curious why the user would be "trying" the wrong path.

Comment: Our backend is a proxy to another backend actually. It is a middle man forwarding request and also transforming some routes. 

We have two group of endpoints

a.com/paid/v1/foo/bar
a.com/trial/v1/foo/bar

Initially, we are thinking about using NGINX to filter out any URL that is neither a.com/paid/* nor a.com/trial/*. 

However, I think user can still try any other URL and our backend still have to handle wrong path.

Is there any value if I use nginx to only allow 
a.com/paid/v1/* and a.com/trial/v1/* ?